# Differential structure on regular submanifold vs. embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and let $F:M\longrightarrow N$ be a smooth embedding. Here the definition of smooth embedding is as follows: 
$$F:M\rightarrow N \;\text{is a one-to-one immersion, and }F:M\rightarrow F(M)\;\text{is a homeomorphism with subspace topology on }F(M)\subset N.$$

1. Then we know that $F(M)$ is an **embedded submanifold** of $N$ with subspace topology. If $\Sigma=\{(U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha}) \}$ is an atlas on $M$, then we know $\{(F(U_{\alpha}),\varphi_{\alpha}\circ F^{-1}\vert_{F(U_{\alpha})}  )\}$ is an atlas on $F(M)$, which determines a differential structure on $F(M)$. We denote this differential structure by $DS_{1}$.
2. Also, we know that $F(M)$ can be viewed as a **regular submanifold** of $N$ with subspace topology. And for each point $p\in F(M)$, there exists a chart $(U,\varphi)$ on $N$, such that $\varphi(U\cap F(M))=\varphi(U)\cap \left(\mathbb{R}^{k} \times \{0\} \right)$. So we know $(U\cap F(M),\varphi |_{U\cap F(M)})$ is a chart around $p$ for this regular submanifold $F(M)$. And this also provides a differential structure on $F(M)$, denoting by $DS_{2}$.

My confusion is: **Must we have $DS_{1}=DS_{2}$?**  Can anyone help me?

=================================================================================================
**Update** ================================
My professor told me a proposition that may work for this problem.

**Proposition:** Let $(M,\tau)$ be a smooth manifold. $\Sigma_{1}$ and $\Sigma_{2}$ are two smooth atlases on $M$. The differential structures they determines denote by $DS_{1}$ and $DS_{2}$ respectively. Then we have $DS_{1}=DS_{2}\Leftrightarrow \Sigma_{1}\cup \Sigma_{2}$ is still a smooth atlas on $M$.

I have tried to use this proposition to solve my problem, as shown in figure. 
[image]

The only thing I need to check is the smoothness of the transition maps  $\phi |_{V\cap F(M)}\circ (\varphi\circ F^{-1})^{-1}$ and $(\varphi\circ F^{-1})\circ\phi^{-1}$. How can I know these two maps are smooth?

Comment: You have to add more details, namely, what , if anything, you assume about F besides that it is a topological embedding. Is it smooth? An immersion?

Comment: I have edited to clarify the background assumptions as seemed to be implied by the rest of the question.  If the details I added are not what you intended please correct them.

Comment: I have added some details. @MoisheKohan

Comment: Thanks, I have just edited again.@EricWofsey

Comment: Prove first that when $F(M)$ is given the structure of a regular submanifold of $N$ then $F : M \to F(M)$ is a diffeomorphism. To do this, use the inverse function theorem to find around each $m \in M$ a chart $(U, \varphi)$ and a chart $(V, \psi)$ around $F(m)$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$, $(V, \psi)$ is a slice chart for $F(M)$ in $N$, and $\psi \circ F \circ \varphi^{-1} : \varphi(U) \to \psi(V)$ is the canonical injection $(x_1, \ldots, x_d) \to (x_1, \ldots, x_d, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Also, to reduce confusion use $U$ and $\varphi$ for charts on $M$ and $V$ and $\psi$ for charts on $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.  Let $X$ denote $F(M)$ with the smooth structure given by $DS_1$ and let $Y$ denote $F(M)$ with the smooth structure given by $DS_2$.  Note first that if $f:P\to N$ is any smooth map from a manifold $P$ whose image is contained in $F(M)$, then $f$ is smoooth as a map to $P\to Y$.  Indeed, just look in a local chart on $N$ as in the definition of $DS_2$: locally, $f$ looks like a smooth map $\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image happens to be contained in $\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}$, and such a map is obviously also smooth when considered as a map to $\mathbb{R}^k$ (since you are just taking the first $k$ coordinates of the map).

Applying this to the inclusion map $X\to M$, we see that the identity map $i:X\to Y$ is smooth.  But also, since $F$ was an immersion, $di$ is injective everywhere (restricting the codomain to $Y$ does not change that, since looking locally and identifying $N=\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y=\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}$, the derivatives of all coordinates of $F$ after the $k$th are identically $0$, so if $dF$ is injective it must still be injective looking at just the first $k$ coordinates).  Note moreover that $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension: by the constant rank theorem, $i:X\to Y$ looks locally like the inclusion $\mathbb{R}^{\dim X}\times\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^{\dim Y}$.  But since $F$ was an embedding, $i$ is a homeomorphism and in particular it is locally an open map, and the inclusion $\mathbb{R}^{\dim X}\times\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^{\dim Y}$ is only an open map if $\dim X=\dim Y$.

Finally, the inverse function theorem now says that $i^{-1}$ is smooth, since $di$ is an isomorphism everywhere.  Thus $i:X\to Y$ is a diffeomorphism, which means the two smooth structures $DS_1$ and $DS_2$ are the same.

Comment: I am still confused...I have added my own thoughts. Would you mind instructing me?